# Angular - Debounce Time Promise<boolean>

Tags: angular, promise, debouncing

I have a method in a service that returns a Promise trigged when a user submit a form.

The problem is that when user clicked x times, he skips x screens.

I am searching about debounce time operator but it works only on Observable. Here I have a Promise.

Any suggestions please ?

```
  goToNextRoute = (queryParams?: Params): Promise<boolean> =>
    this.routeRecursive(this.getNextRoute, queryParams);
```

Comment: How about use observable and thus the `debounceTime` that gets shipped with angular anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Either you can implement your own debounce function

```
function debounce(f, interval) {
  let timer = null;

  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      timer = setTimeout(
        () => resolve(f(...args)),
        interval,
      );
    });
  };
}
```

OR you can use debounce function from lodash

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce

```
_.debounce(somethingThatReturnsAPromise, interval, {
  leading: true,
  trailing: false
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Emits everytime the user clicks*/
private goToNextRouteClick = new Subject<Params | undefined>(); 

constructor(){
  this.goToNextRoute.pipe(debounceTime(TIME)).subscribe( params => 
  this.routeRecursive(this.getNextRoute, queryParams) )
}

/** Callback to goToNextRoute button*/
public goToNextRoute = (queryParams?: Params) => this.goToNextRoute.next(queryParams);
```

I don't know about your code but you should maybe unsubscribe in the ngOnDestroy()